# Make inlined JS Configuration object CSP-compliant (CSP Level 1)

Tags: javascript, configuration, content-security-policy

My web application (JS part) needs to be configured by the server before loading. 
Right now it is done in the following manner:

```
<script>
var configObj = {
setting1: "blah",
setting2: {val1: 1, val2:2},
};
</script>
<script src="myapp.js">
```

Config is request-specific and is inlined by server when html response is built.
It works well, but it violates `unsafe-inline` Content-Security Policy rule.

unfortunately we can't just rely on CSP Level 2 (hashes/nonces), we are stuck with Level 1 for now.
Is there a proved/recommended way of configuring client app in a CSP-compliant way?

So far I am thinking about embedding it into some DOM element as string and then JSON.parsing it. Are there any other (better) options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can move all config options into data-* attributes and then read them in then script.
- If you're worried about the compatibility of nonces, you may find [this article](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/content-security-policy-for-single-page-web-apps-78f2b2cf1757#.cqfo42sio) interesting.